# Prediction model on hybrid data

Tags: categorical-data, predictive-models, prediction

I am currently working with a data set where I have both continuous, discrete and categorical (without any order) data. And I have to predict a continuous data. To be concrete, my problem is a classical one which aims at predicting the cost of a flat in a city considering many data about it:

1- Area (continuous)

2- Number of rooms (discrete)

3- Is there a parking spot (discrete)

4- Name of the city (categorical)

5- Year of building (discrete)

6- Orientation (categorical -> N, S, W, E)

7- Luminosity (continuous)

I know you can transform categorical data into discrete by labelling them but it means giving an order on those values which is not implied by their nature. I was wondering if there were better approaches. I know some algorithm dealing with:

1- Continuous parameter -> continuous prediction (regression)

2- Continuous parameter -> discrete prediction (logistic regression, SVM...)

3- Discrete parameter -> discrete prediction (neural networks...)

But I have never worked with categorical values (or I considered them as discrete). And I have never implemented an hybrid model working with all types of data. Do you have advice for this kind of problem? It is an open question, so you can answer by algorithm names, links or books.

Comment: I believe you're mistaken. linear regression, logistic regression etc all allow for continious+discrete predictors. The housing market dataset has been presented fairly often so might easily be able to find example using both. google should provide you will linear regression example for your chosen statistical program